# Spring Tool Suite 4: not possible to open projects after the update to version 4.5.0

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have updated the version of Spring Tool Suite 4 (from the penultimate to the last Version: 4.5.0.RELEASE Build Id: 201912171052) which includes Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle 3.1.3.v20191118-1057.

Now I can't open some projects, I have this error:

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Errors occurred while refreshing resources with the local file system. build.gradle
```

I tried commands like gradlew install / gradlew cleaneclipse eclipse...

How can I to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by checking this option in Spring Tool Suite 4

[image]